# Mixed mode DLL requires delay loading

Tags: com, c++-cli

I've created a mixed DLL (C++/CLI) and after successfully calling it from a plain ANSI C application, I've moved on to calling it from a C++ COM server (using the same C entry points). However even before the COM server successfully starts or calls into the DLL I get a "access violation" in ntdll.dll.  The call stack just has ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler2 repeated multiple times to the point where a stack over flow is reported in the VS debug output. I can see my mixed mode DLL and mscoree.dll are loaded.

I added the mixed DLL to the delay loaded DLL options of the COM server and it appears to work.

Why does the mixed DLL need to be delay loaded in the C++ COM Server when the C application I wrote seems to work fine without delay loading? How do I go about debugging this problem (unless this is expected, however I couldn't find anything about it)?

Comment: Sounds like LoaderLock, can't load the CLR when DllMain runs.  Trap the exception when it is thrown with Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a [COM Appartment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) needs to be initialized. COM appartments are used to care of threads synchronization.